# Abstract Algebra Automorphism - Is my answer Correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, automorphism-group

Hope you are well.

Im posting the following as a favor on behalf of a friend who is not a native speaker, she just wants to confirm her answer is indeed correct.

Q: show that the set of all automorphism functions of G is a group under composition.

[image of full answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRWk.jpg)

A: (h ∘ g)∘ f = h ∘ (g∘ f)

(h ∘ g)(a)∘ f(a) = h( g(a))∘
f(a) =h [ f(a)g(a) ]

h(a)∘(g ∘ f)(a) =h(a) ∘
[ g(f(a))]= h [f(a)g(a)]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your translation seems to have mangled the problem statement. Your equation involving h,g,f is not a set, it's just an equation - but it is an equation that is relevant to checking associativity, of course. Is $G$ a group, and you're trying to show the automorphisms form a group under composition? If so, she also needs to show the composition of two automorphisms is another automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i have made an edit and asked for an image of her answer to hopefully make it clearer. Thanks again.

Comment: Your image correctly shows the composition of two automorphisms is an automorphism. And the text in your original post shows function composition is associative. The last thing that needs to be mentioned to show ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a group is that there is an identity element (which is of course the identity function $f(g)=g$ for all $g\in G$).

Comment: @runway44: And that every element has a compositional inverse....

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys...it helped her a lot : )

Comment: Associativity is for free, because automorphisms are in particular bijections on one same set. The indentity map is operation-preserving. So, you are left with proving closure and closure by inverses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, and then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a group if and only if $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\le\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Therefore we have to prove that $\forall \sigma,\tau\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, both $\sigma\tau\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $\sigma^{-1}\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, namely that both $\sigma\tau$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are operation-preserving:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(\sigma\tau)(gh) &= \sigma(\tau(gh)) \\
&= \sigma(\tau(g)\tau(h)) \\
&= \sigma(\tau(g))\sigma(\tau(h)) \\
&= (\sigma\tau)(g)(\sigma\tau)(h) \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

and:

\begin{alignat}{1}
gh=gh &\Rightarrow \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(gh))=\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(g))\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(h)) \\
&\Rightarrow \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(gh))=\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(g)\sigma^{-1}(h)) \\
&\Rightarrow \sigma^{-1}(gh)=\sigma^{-1}(g)\sigma^{-1}(h) \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}